# Ingress route for all paths in a host

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I have a local test environment with k3s. 
I am trying to reach a local jenkins pod running in one of the k3s workers via ingress.
I have configured the ingress object to answer on a specific host for all paths, but it doesnt seem to work.
 Im always getting 404 in the traefik logs.
Is there a way to check how the request is flowing?

The configs:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins
spec:
  rules:
    - host: jenkins.homelab.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: jenkins
                port: 
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Check that the jenkins service name and the port matches your ingress definition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your IngressClass isn'n set to default so your ingress is not allocated to it.

Try to set it specific in the ingress:

```
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    ...
```

Or by setting your ingress class to default:

```
kubectl patch ingressclass nginx -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'
```

Where 'nginx' is the name of your IngressClass.

Answer (score 0):

When the ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class annotation is set to true on an IngressClass resource, new Ingresses will be assigned this default IngressClass even if no ingressClassName field is specified.

```
annotations:
   ingressclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
```

Multiple Ingress objects on one Ingress use the below annotations:

```
annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Make sure metadata.name is one-of-a-kind. If metadata.name is the same for each object, the new configuration simply replaces it.

Follow the  [Ingress path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) for your issue, here is a [blog](https://tech.forums.softwareag.com/t/how-to-configure-path-based-routing-with-ingress-on-kubernetes-cluster/240535) explaining the path matching